# Drupal 8 Custom front page issue

Tags: theming

I have created a custom front page in my theme (`page--front.html.twig`) and put some custom content which is coming up as expected as long as I am not logged in. But when I log in as admin, I cannot browse the homepage anymore. Rather Drupal always takes me to `eventcloud.dd:8083/user/1`. Even if I manually modify the URL to `eventcloud.dd:8083/` it gets redirected to the above URL, i.e. with `user/1`.

To double check I created an Authenticated User (without administrative rights) and logged in with this account. Same thing happens. Why the system navigates to another page and not staying on the homepage? How to fix this so that homepage only loads up homepage?

I initially created a page `upcoming-events` and set it up as my default homepage from admin/config/system/site-information. I removed that and presently there is no homepage defined separately.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `admin/config/system/site-information` and set the default front page to `/node`. I think what you describe is related to the Views module which provides the default frontpage in Drupal 8.